# How to merge 2 Dataframes by datetime of one df has only dates and the other is indexed hourly

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

i have two dataframes. One is indexed by dates (daily), containing values valid for the whole day  and the other is indexed by datetime (hourly) containing values for every hour.

DF1

```
date                A       B       C       D       F       
2017-07-01 11:00:00 2505.56 2513.38 2495.12 2509.17 287000.32
2017-07-01 12:00:00 2509.17 2512.87 2484.99 2488.43 393142.50
2017-07-01 13:00:00 2488.43 2488.43 2454.40 2454.43 693254.01
2017-07-01 14:00:00 2454.43 2473.93 2450.83 2459.35 712864.80
...
2017-07-02 16:00:00 2463.86 2479.25 2462.17 2476.41 1075573.75
2017-07-02 17:00:00 2476.41 2507.54 2474.23 2496.37 3030780.24
2017-07-02 18:00:00 2496.37 2526.72 2490.00 2490.08 2003965.15
2017-07-02 19:00:00 2490.08 2506.11 2478.43 2492.61 1619701.03
...
```

DF2

```
date        G
07-05-2017  56
07-04-2017  52
07-03-2017  56
07-02-2017  53
07-01-2917  56
```

Now i need to concat the two dataframes with assigning the values of on day in DF2 to all 24 hours in DF1.

The result should look something like this.

DF3

```
date                A       B       C       D       F           G
2017-07-01 11:00:00 2505.56 2513.38 2495.12 2509.17 287000.32   56
2017-07-01 12:00:00 2509.17 2512.87 2484.99 2488.43 393142.50   56
2017-07-01 13:00:00 2488.43 2488.43 2454.40 2454.43 693254.01   56
2017-07-01 14:00:00 2454.43 2473.93 2450.83 2459.35 712864.80   56
...
2017-07-02 16:00:00 2463.86 2479.25 2462.17 2476.41 1075573.75  53
2017-07-02 17:00:00 2476.41 2507.54 2474.23 2496.37 3030780.24  53
2017-07-02 18:00:00 2496.37 2526.72 2490.00 2490.08 2003965.15  53
2017-07-02 19:00:00 2490.08 2506.11 2478.43 2492.61 1619701.03  53
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

Use `merge_asof` here:

```
df1['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['date'])
df2['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['date'])
df1.sort_values('date', inplace=True)
df2.sort_values('date', inplace=True)

df = pd.merge_asof(df1, df2, on='date')
print(df)

                 date        A        B        C        D           F   G
0 2017-07-01 11:00:00  2505.56  2513.38  2495.12  2509.17   287000.32  56
1 2017-07-01 12:00:00  2509.17  2512.87  2484.99  2488.43   393142.50  56
2 2017-07-01 13:00:00  2488.43  2488.43  2454.40  2454.43   693254.01  56
3 2017-07-01 14:00:00  2454.43  2473.93  2450.83  2459.35   712864.80  56
4 2017-07-02 16:00:00  2463.86  2479.25  2462.17  2476.41  1075573.75  53
5 2017-07-02 17:00:00  2476.41  2507.54  2474.23  2496.37  3030780.24  53
6 2017-07-02 18:00:00  2496.37  2526.72  2490.00  2490.08  2003965.15  53
7 2017-07-02 19:00:00  2490.08  2506.11  2478.43  2492.61  1619701.03  53
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the column date has identical format in both tables, you may get the desired result by executing the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import pandasql as pds
a=pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\kemot\\Desktop\\programy Python\\a.txt',sep=' ')
b=a.iloc[:,:6]
c=pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\kemot\\Desktop\\programy Python\\b.txt',sep=' ')
d=c.iloc[:,:2]
w=pds.sqldf("""select b.*, G from b join d on b.date=d.date""",locals())
```

You can use merge method on one of two df's but to me sql is simpler and easier to understand. Pandasql is a module that enables performing sql queries on df's.